# Concatenate muliple images with pillow in python

Tags: python

I have searched for this topic of how to merge or concatenate multiple images using python.

```
from PIL import Image

def get_concat_v():
    dst = Image.new('RGB', (im1.width, im1.height + im2.height + im3.height + im4.height))
    dst.paste(im1, (0, 0))
    dst.paste(im2, (0, im1.height))
    dst.paste(im3, (0, im1.height + im2.height))
    dst.paste(im4, (0, im1.height + im2.height + im3.height))
    return dst

im1 = Image.open('First.png')
im2 = Image.open('Second.png')
im3 = Image.open('Third.png')
im4 = Image.open('Fourth.png')
get_concat_v().save('concat_v.png')
```

How can I loop through a folder that has multiple images (Say 9 images) and merge every four images into one image? So the final folder should have three images (the first image would contain 4 images, the second image would contain 4 images, the third image would contain 1 image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you're looking for?

It uses [`more_itertools.chunked`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.chunked) to get image file paths in groups of four, including the final group which may be less than four. I also rewrote your concatenation function to accept any number of images, and expand to fit the widest one, if their widths differ.

```
from pathlib import Path

from more_itertools import chunked
from PIL import Image


def concat_images(*images):
    """Generate composite of all supplied images."""
    # Get the widest width.
    width = max(image.width for image in images)
    # Add up all the heights.
    height = sum(image.height for image in images)
    composite = Image.new('RGB', (width, height))
    # Paste each image below the one before it.
    y = 0
    for image in images:
        composite.paste(image, (0, y))
        y += image.height
    return composite


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Define the folder to operate on (currently set to the current
    # working directory).
    images_dir = Path('.')
    # Define where to save the output (shown here, will be in `output`
    # inside the images dir).
    output_dir = images_dir / 'output'
    # Create the output folder, if it doesn't already exist.
    output_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

    # Iterate through the .png files in groups of four, using an index
    # to name the resulting output.
    png_paths = images_dir.glob('*.png')
    for i, paths in enumerate(chunked(png_paths, 4), start=1):
        images = [Image.open(path) for path in paths]
        composite = concat_images(*images)
        composite.save(output_dir / f'{i}.png')
```

Comment: Is there a way to enhance the resolution of the new created images?

Comment: Another question: Is it possible to add white space after the fourth picture (the dimensions would be the same width and half-height of the last image)?

Comment: What do you mean "enhance the resolution"? Do you want them bigger? And for the second question, sure,  just add half the height of the last image to the total height, `+ images[-1].height // 2`.

Comment: I mean by enhance not to make them bigger to make them clearer (maybe black pixels are instense). As for the white part just white pixels (the same width as any of the images and the half-height of any image)

Comment: That sounds like a separate question to research/ask about.

Comment: Is it possible to have padding white space between each of the images when merged?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71488666/have-padding-white-space-between-each-image

Answer (score 0):

Trying to improve upon the already present answer.
You can join 4 images in a folder at a time getting their filenames with `os.listdir()` and composing every 4 iterations.

```
from PIL import Image
import os

def get_concat_v(im1, im2, im3, im4):
    dst = Image.new('RGB', (im1.width, im1.height + im2.height + im3.height + im4.height))
    dst.paste(im1, (0, 0))
    dst.paste(im2, (0, im1.height))
    dst.paste(im3, (0, im1.height + im2.height))
    dst.paste(im4, (0, im1.height + im2.height + im3.height))
    return dst

images = []
for i, filename in enumerate(os.listdir("yourdirectory")):
    images.append(Image.open(filename)) # keep track of read image
    if i % 3 == 0: # every 4 images, save a new one
        res = get_concat_v(images[0], images[1], images[2], images[3])
        res.save("somewhere")
        images = []
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got error at this line `images.append(Image.open(filename))`. `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:` although there is a file with that name. The images are in folder named `Stickers` and the output will be in an existing folder named `Final`.

Comment: Well I think you can fix that error and the output by changing the directories names...

Comment: I declared a variable `directory = "./Stickers/"` and use it in line `images.append(Image.open(directory + filename))`. But now I got a different error ` res = get_concat_v(images[0], images[1], images[2], images[3])` `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: check when that happens by doing prints of the variables of interest

Comment: I already tried but couldn't find a clue. Did you try your code? (The folder on my side has 9 images and I need to merge each four images into one so the final folder would have three images and the third one will have one sticker)