# Have padding white space between each image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

In a previous question on the following link [Concatenate muliple images with pillow in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71303878/concatenate-muliple-images-with-pillow-in-python), I got the following code that merges each four images together. The code is working very well and I appreciate that to @CrazyChucky

```
from pathlib import Path

from more_itertools import chunked
from PIL import Image


def concat_images(*images):
    """Generate composite of all supplied images."""
    # Get the widest width.
    width = max(image.width for image in images)
    # Add up all the heights.
    height = sum(image.height for image in images)
    composite = Image.new('RGB', (width, height))
    # Paste each image below the one before it.
    y = 0
    for image in images:
        composite.paste(image, (0, y))
        y += image.height
    return composite


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Define the folder to operate on (currently set to the current
    # working directory).
    images_dir = Path('.')
    # Define where to save the output (shown here, will be in `output`
    # inside the images dir).
    output_dir = images_dir / 'output'
    # Create the output folder, if it doesn't already exist.
    output_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

    # Iterate through the .png files in groups of four, using an index
    # to name the resulting output.
    png_paths = images_dir.glob('*.png')
    for i, paths in enumerate(chunked(png_paths, 4), start=1):
        images = [Image.open(path) for path in paths]
        composite = concat_images(*images)
        composite.save(output_dir / f'{i}.png')
```

My question is how to add padding white space between each image?

I have found this function that helps me a lot (I put it for others to make use of it)

```
def add_margin(pil_img, top, right, bottom, left, color):
    width, height = pil_img.size
    new_width = width + right + left
    new_height = height + top + bottom
    result = Image.new(pil_img.mode, (new_width, new_height), color)
    result.paste(pil_img, (left, top))
    return result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems pretty clear.  You just need to pad the height for the image.

```
def concat_images(*images):
    """Generate composite of all supplied images."""
    # Get the widest width.
    width = max(image.width for image in images)
    # Add up all the heights.
    padding = 10
    height = sum(image.height+padding for image in images) - padding
    composite = Image.new('RGB', (width, height))
    # Paste each image below the one before it.
    y = 0
    for image in images:
        composite.paste(image, (0, y))
        y += image.height + padding
    return composite
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much. Just one point, how can I make the padding white as I tried and I got black padding? please don't modify the whole code, just refer to me to learn that point.

Comment: Where do you think the black comes from?  It's the original background of the image you create.  That is, `composite` starts out all black.  So, you need to ask yourself, "how do I specify a background color"?

Comment: In fact, the original image is TIFF of two pages (I mean one tiff image that has two page) and I am using the code to split these two embedded images in the tiff into one. So every two images will be merged into one. I don't have idea how to let the white space between each page, but I found a function (added to the question) that solves the problem)

Comment: Is it possible to your modification to let the padding be white?

Comment: Hi, guys.
try to use ``composite = Image.new('RGB', (width, height), color = (255, 255, 255))``, ``color =  (255, 255, 255)`` makes the padding white.